# C# cmd.exe process write output to window And redirect output

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am using a `Process` to run the cmd.exe in C# (WinForms).

I am able to redirect the standard output (either by capturing the event or reading the StreamReader) to a .txt file:

```
private async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(string command)
{
    using var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += CommandPrompt_OutputReceived;

    // ...
}
```

and I'm able to write the output directly to the console window:

```
private async Task ExecuteCommandWithWindowAsync(string command)
{
    using var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

    // ...
}
```

But I can't find any way of doing both, i.e. write to the console window AND redirect the standard output to a .txt file.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something obvious? Or will I need to grab the string in a different way?

Comment: @shingo oh man, I thought I searched all the SO relevant questions. I feel I prize idiot. Thanks for the link.

Comment: WHy are you running `cmd` to run other commands, why don't you just run those commands directly?